# SQL select a column value that is not zero and if there are multiple values to select the last one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns called NAME and NUMB.

```
NAME   NUMB
John   0
Sam    0
Tom    1
Bob    0
Tom    0
Ryu    2
Ken    0
```

I would like to use some SQL to select that **last** number in that table that isn't a zero.  So my results should show up as "2".  If the 2 was a zero then my results would be "1".  What would be the best way.  Thanks!

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no concept of "last" row in a table, unless you have column that specifies the ordering such as an auto-incremented id or creation date.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the 0 values, order by number descending and take the first row.

```
SELECT numb
FROM myTable
WHERE num != 0
ORDER BY numb DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Of course I supposed you wanted the biggest value in the columns since there's no "last" row in mysql.

Comment: That will return biggest number not the last.

Comment: There's no "last", unless there's a date field, if it would be the case you could query the "latest".

Comment: @EndeNeu Any reason why you would use `LIMIT 1` at the end instead of `TOP 1` at the beginning? or does it not make a difference?

Comment: `MySQL` has no `TOP` has far as I know, `SQL` does.

Comment: Obviously, but modifying the question so it fits your answer to rather trivial problem isn't really helping. You'd actually help more by supposing there WAS a date field and solving it then. This way you'd at least feed others curiousity if nothing else.

Comment: @mareckmareck I had no intention to do so, I simply thought that OP meant the greatest value in the column since he said "_If the 2 was a zero then my results would be "1"_", that makes me think about taking the biggest value and not the latest date or the latest auto incremented primary key value. I may be wrong of course but so do you since we are all interpreting, if op requirements will change/be more specific I'll be glad to change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "last" dataset in SQL. Unordered sets are one of the core principles...

A workaround might be to add another column that auto increments with each inserted row. This way you could just query the Max(auto_increment_row) and get the dataset that was last inserted.

Of course you'll need an additional check if that value is 0 and take according action if it is. There are multiple approaches to that, so just come back to us if you have any concrete problems with the SQL query you tried.